# How do I show that this function is not smooth?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, smooth-manifolds

Let $D \subset \Bbb R^n$ be the open unit disc.
I want to show that the function $f : D \rightarrow D$ which sends $$(x_1,...,x_n) \mapsto \Vert (x_1,...,x_n) \Vert (x_1,...,x_n)$$ is not smooth at the origin.  Here, $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is the Euclidean norm.

I know that $f$ is a homeomorphism.  I want to show that both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are smooth on $D \backslash \{0\}$.

I started to look at the following limit:

$$\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}(0,..,0) =\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f_1(t,0,...,0)}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0} |t| = 0.$$

It seems that I should look at the second partial derivatives at $0$.  I thought about considering the second symmetric derivative, but I do not think this will work.  What do you recommend?

Thank you.

Comment: I think 2nd derivative will work, when $n=1$, $f(x)=x|x|$, $f'(x)=2|x|$, the function is $C^1$ but not $C^2$. Same thing is probably true for general $n$.